# JQuery Help Needed - Dynamically Creating A Expanding/Collapsing Quick Launch

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently running into a bit of a problem.

I need to make my Sharepoint 2010 site have an expanding/collapsing quick launch navigation. There are many Sharepoint 2007 solutions and web-parts out there that do exactly what I need. See [this example.](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2008/12/03/jquery-for-everyone-accordion-left-nav/)

However, Sharepoint 2010 does not generate the quick launch HTML the same way as it does in 2007.

The 2007 Sharepoint quick launch is generated with tables and uses plenty of ID's, while 2010 generates an unordered list with no ID's.

**Because this is generated code I do not want to touch the markup.**

The basic markup is as follows:

```
<div class="menu vertical menu-vertical">
    <ul class="root static">
        <li class="static">
            <span class="static menu-item">
                <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">MAIN HEADING</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item" href="">
                <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Sub Heading</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="static">
            <span class="static menu-item">
                <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">MAIN HEADING</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item" href="">
                <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Sub Heading</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="static">
            <a class="static menu-item" href="">
                <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Sub Heading</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There can be any number of Main Headings and Sub Headings in the future.

My idea was to use JQuery selectors to separate the Main Headings from the Sub Headings. I'm able to do that by selecting by class and then by li's that contain anchors inside but I'm having trouble grouping the headings to the sub headings.

I need to find a way to make Heading 1's onClick event correspond to the Sub Headings under it, and not to the other Sub Headings in the document.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: find() only searches descendants (http://api.jquery.com/find/), so using something like $(this).find('.subheadingclass') might work to get only sub headings under the current heading (assumes that $(this) is your heading element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go (even tested it):

```
    $(function() {
        //hide sub headings
        $('li:has(a.menu-item)').hide();
        //show subs on parent click
        $('li:has(span.menu-item)').click(function() {
            //get sub headings and show them
            $(this).nextUntil('li:has(span.menu-item)').toggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: But my Main Heading and Sub Headings are siblings, will that work?

Comment: @Ryan - I think I'm starting to understand the problem better. I misunderstood the problem. (who at microsoft made a menu that renders like this!?!) The only difference between a main heading and a sub heading is that one has an <a href class="menu-item" in it and the other has a <span class="menu-item". Let me think on this for a bit...

Comment: @Ryan - I updated the code and it's straightforward and simple.

Comment: Thanks! Works great, even better than my solution!

Answer (score 2):

This works and it keeps the Heading linkable and the submenu open when you click the submenu items.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// do stuff when DOM is ready

makeLNCollapsible();
}); 
function makeLNCollapsible()
{
$("div.menu-vertical>ul.root>li.static>a").toggle(
function () {
var menuitem = $(this);
$(">ul", $(this).parent()).show("fast", function() { window.location = menuitem.attr('href');});
},
function () {
$(">ul", $(this).parent()).hide("fast");
     }
); 

$("li.static>ul.static").css("display","none");
$selectedEntry = $('li.static>ul.static .selected');
if($selectedEntry.length>0) {
    $selectedEntry.parent().css("display", "block");

}
$selectedEntry = $('li.static.selected');
if($selectedEntry.length > 0) {
    $selectedEntry.children('ul.static').css("display", "block");


}
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on the SP2010 site:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".s4-ql ul.root > li > .menu-item").click(function(){
            $(this).next('ul').toggle('slow');

        });

    }); 




</script>
```

Note I hide the subheadings in a custom css so that there is no delay on page load:
/*hide sub menus*/
.s4-ql UL.root UL{
    display:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, on the onclick of the main heading, just traverse to the parent li by using parentsUntil('li'), then use next('li a') (or just li) to get to the next li with the sub heading and traverse as you need there.

Might be a bit too clumsy solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I found that the nextAll() function did exactly what I needed.

```
        $(".menu.vertical.menu-vertical > .root.static > li > span").parent().addClass('MainHeading');
        $('.MainHeading').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(".menu.vertical.menu-vertical > .root.static > li > a").parent().addClass('SubHeading');

        $('.MainHeading').click(function(){
                $(this).nextAll('li').each(function(){
                    elm = $(this)

                    if(elm.hasClass('MainHeading')){
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(elm.hasClass('SubHeading')){
                        if(elm.css('display') == 'none')
                        {
                            elm.show();
                        }
                        else{
                            elm.hide();
                        }

                    }
                });
        });
```